# How can I avoid "Warning: String or Binary data would be truncated" in an SQL job giving me a failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I've already looked at this, but none of the solutions I've seen and tried actually solve me issue.

Background: using SQL server 2005

When I run a stored procedure to insert data into a table it works fine. If I get an SQL job to run that same stored procedure over the same data, the job runs successfully, but the data is NOT inserted into the same destination table.

I've tried the `SET ansi_warnings OFF`, but I get an error compiling the SQL, saying

> Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.

Table schema:

```
[JobNo] [int] 
[ProductCode] [varchar](20) 
[ProductName] [varchar](200)
[ReportedAvailability] [varchar](100) 
[ReportedProductClean] [varchar](100)
[ReportedProductDate] [varchar](100) 
[ReportedProductPrice] [int] 
[ReportedCasesOrdered] [int] 
[AvailableYes] [int] 
[AvailableOOS] [int] 
[AvailableNotRanged] 
[ProductClean] [int] 
[ProductInDate] [int]
[ProductPrice] [int] 
[CasesOrdered] [int] 
[Include] [int] 
[Counter] [int] 
[UserId] [varchar](10) 
[Modified] [datetime]
```

In the cursor, there is a try/catch around the insert statement, so as it processes the jobs one by one, if there is a problem, I know exactly which job it failed on, as there is an update statement to say "complete" if it's ok, "failed" if not.

All the data I am putting into this table is short enough to fit into the require columns (i.e. product names are less than 200 characters, INT values are 5 digits or less).

I get a warning, not an error, but I can't understand why it fails legitimate records when run as a SQL Job, but not when it's run as a stand alone SP.

There are no triggers on the destination table, there are a few default to 0 constraints on the INT columns (but I wouldn't have thought that would be the issue. Other tables in the same SP don't have this issue)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the data for `UserId`? If it's the current user then the account that SQL Agent runs as may be longer than your user account.

Comment: You're probably trying to insert a `varchar(101+)` in one of the `varchar(100)`, or a `varchar(11+)` into the `UserId` column. An easy (/ugly) fix could be to truncate the data yourself by inserting, for example, `left(src.UserId, 10)` instead of just `src.UserId`.

Comment: Check the permissions of the account that the SQL Job is running under. I've had the same results when someone did a DROP/CREATE instead of a ALTER for a table or SP.  Also, is it possible that an error is being thrown within your cursor and the truncate warning is happening when you log the error?

Comment: Is there any manipulation of varchar variables inside stored procedure or directly insert? Please ensure there is no whitespace by using LTRIM(RTRIM()) around varchar variables

Comment: Is there a linked server involved and possibly permission issue reading the data?

Comment: There is a linked server involved, but again, permissions are set up to be able to read data (reading from linked server, inserting into Local)

Comment: @dpw - the UserId is a 10 character string added manually, so I know that will fit.

Comment: @retailcoder - I've checked the lengths of the incoming data and it's all limited to values lower than the varchar values of the destination table

Comment: @tgolisch - I don't think so, but I'll double check. The queue to be processed comes from another table in the same SQL database as the destination table. There is a comments field that I update with the error, but so far I've not seen anything that looks like a truncated error message in that field. The job itself writes to a txt file to log what's happened, we've never had issues writing long strings to one of those

Comment: @user2440816 you can try creating a dev/test copy of your destination table, and then grabbing a failing record and trying to script insert it with stub (valid) values for all fields except one (which takes the field value from the failing record); put all these inserts (one for each destination field) in the same script, and when you run it the failing line will tell you which field blows up.

Comment: If the comments field that you are updating with the error is the problem, then you won't see any messages that look truncated, because they are erroring-out (instead of being inserted/truncated).  Try using a substring command in your insert command to make sure it is not too long, before attempting to insert an error message.

Comment: @user2440816 Do any of your local variables used for pulling values from your cursor within your proc have different datatypes than the corresponding columns in the table you are inserting into?  This would include any variables that are just declared as `varchar` without explicitly having the varchar length in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any error when it comes to running a job or direct stored procedure unless there are logic within the job that causes some of your data to be longer than expected. I used so many jobs and stored procedure but I never encounter such error. On a developer standpoint, errors in jobs occur only if: 1) failure on the executing account or lacks of access, 2) there's really an error with the executing stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

The info is really limited so cant be conclusive. If you are saying on a default query window connection you are able to execute without any issues so settings could one aspect. cant you assign all these values onto some variables before insert against tables. Setting the values to variables will facilitate automatic truncation to the specified variable length and you can avoid error